# Trig Equation: Sin2x=0.6, between and equal to 0-360.

Tags: trigonometry

Sin2x=0.6, between and equal to 0-360.
So, for this question, firstly I inversed sin on each side, leaving me with 2x= 36.8699...
Then I divided both sides by 2 to get x, since sin was positive, I only marked the first 2 quadrants on a CAST diagram, then, marked 18.4 (x to 1d.p.) and 161.6.
I thought these where the answers but this was my first question like this so I checked it against the answers. They said my first answer of 18.4 is correct but not my second one, not only this but they list 4 answers. How did I get my second one wrong? and why is there more than 2 answers, should I have used more than 2 quadrants?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it can be understood by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Please understand that not everyone read the exact same textbook you are going through, and did not attend the exact same class. So we are not aware of the specific jargon you are using in your description, which is even more of a problem when you abbreviate that jargon, and expect us to understand the abbreviation. Much of what you describe as your steps is unintelligible.

Comment: Mnemonic devices such as CAST are not universal.  Since I am familiar with the mnemonic "All students take calculus", I am guessing that CAST means cosine is positive in the fourth quadrant, all trigonometric functions are positive in the first quadrant, sine is positive in the second quadrant, and tangent is positive in the third quadrant.  However, you cannot expect readers from around the world to know this mnemonic device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite not being able to follow your description of the steps you took, the mistake you made stands out.

As you know, $\sin \theta$ will take on every value between $1$ and $-1$ twice for angles $0^\circ \le \theta < 360^\circ$, except for $1$ and $-1$ themselves, which are only taken on once.

But in your problem, $\theta = 2x$. Your error was mistaking $x$ for being the angle. The angle isn't $x$, it is $\theta = 2x$. But it is $x$ that is given the restriction of $0^\circ \le x < 360^\circ$. That restriction means

$$0^\circ \le \theta < 720^\circ$$

And in that angle range, sine takes on every value other $1$ and $-1$ four times, not twice.

So you found that $\theta = \sin^{-1}0.6 \approx 36.87^\circ$. The next value of $\theta \approx 180^\circ - 36.87^\circ$, and the other two can be found by adding $360^\circ$ to these two. It is only after making these calculations to find the angles $\theta$, that you divide them by $2$ to get the values of $x$ itself.